# Google Sheets Dynamic Search Range

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get a dynamic search range. This is my current formula...

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B2:B"&row(), B2:B)))
```

I want to get a current count as you move down the sheet of how many times a string has been mentioned. For example, the word `quote`. The first row has the word quote. So in the "times mentioned" column C it should say 1. 5 rows later column  B again says quote. Column C should say 2.

How do I get the formula to recognize the first row to be B2:B2 and the second occurrence in row 5 to B2:B5?

Answer (score 0):

You might try, in Row1:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row()<=countif(B:B,"quote"),Row(),""))
```

copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

### EXACT MATCH:

**dynamic with helping column:**

**B1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="quote", 1, ))`

**C1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B="", , SUMIF(ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B), B1:B)))`

[image]

---

### PARTIAL MATCH:

**B1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "quote"))="quote", 1, ))`

**C1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B="", , SUMIF(ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B), B1:B)))`

[image: 0]